# bunch of weird characters instead of text

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio, unicode, encode

I really count on your help.

Well, for hours I've been trying to have my excel files inserted in sql database as a table through the msvs and no matter what I have tried, the output data is always some sets of weird characters, boxes and etc. First I thought that it could be the PC language settings, I've tried changing them to my local one, changed the system locale to my own language and etc. But there was no result. 
Then I just opened an excel file, typed there a single letter "d" and tried to open it in notepad++ to check whether the result will be the same or not. It was again a big pile of boxes and symbols instead of single letter "d". *Tried to change the encoding in notepad++, didnt work either.

Do you have any idea what can help me? It's really frustrating.

Thanks

Sabuhi.

Comment: To open an Excel file with notepad++, you must save the file as ***.csv***

Comment: I've tried that with the initial file where there was an actual data. There were still boxes and symbols instead of text :/

Answer (score 0):

Of course that happens, **this is common behaviour when you are trying to open a compiled program in a text editor**.

---

> As @Gary'sStudent suggested, if you want to open the excel file
>   directly in a text-editor, it needs to be saved as `.csv`

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
2. Select the `.csv` file type:

   [image]
3. Save (may need to adjust your table data to fit the `.csv` formatting

---

Either way, it sounds like you're a bit confused with what you're trying to achieve. If you want to export your Excel file as a database *(which has it's own quirks and is not exactly the best approach to databases)* then you should be able to view your database in your database editor - whatever you're using,  after you have imported it and compiled it, instead of trying to open it in a text file!